# Use Ansible Postgres Modules to Authorize a view

Tags: ansible

I have Postgres 9.4 view that I wish to allow Select on, I do the following

```
- postgresql_privs: >
database={{ services.oos.db }}
state=present
privs=SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
type=view
objs=ALL_IN_SCHEMA
schema=my_schema
roles=my_users
sudo_user: postgres
tags: [api, customer]
```

That results in the following error

```
msg: value of type must be one of: table,sequence,function,database,schema,language,tablespace,group, got: view
```

Is it possible to do this with Ansible Postgres module functionality or must I resort to a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if you specify the view name, then permissions will apply. This is undocumented and possibly subject to breaking future changes.

```
- postgresql_privs: >
database={{ services.oos.db }}
state=present
privs=SELECT
type=table
objs=some_view
schema=bnr
roles={{ services.oos.db_user }}
sudo_user: postgres
tags: [api]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/5e82f7e11e0ac7cc7cdaeffb0787209afae79fb0/database/postgresql/postgresql_privs.py#L47) you see that `view` is not a valid choice. It's probably easy to extend (your chance for a pull request), but currently it's not supported.